# Problem while replacing %a with the link on the word

Tags: javascript

Here link will be on the first `TEST` word, but `%a` will be replaced with `TEST`.
I need to have a link on the last `TEST` word, instead of `%a`.

```json
{
  text: "String for TEST. The link is here %a.",
  action: "https://www.google.com/",
  action_title: "TEST"
}
```

Comment: Can you put your code to handle this string replacement?

Comment: It`s about this.
res.send({
   text: "String for TEST. The link is here %a.",
   action: "https://www.google.com/",
   action_title: "TEST"
})

Answer (score 0):

```js
const txt = "String for TEST. The link is here %a."
const txtReplaced = txt.replace('%a.', 'https://www.google.com/')
console.log(txtReplaced)
```

Comment: I need to have "String for TEST. The link is here TEST(link on this word)

Comment: Yeah, but i can`t use html

Comment: How will the link be displayed then?

Comment: I send the object(with text, action and action_title) to front, they display theirselves

Comment: @EdgarGhazaryan, are you referring any view template engine?

Comment: @Wazeed idk what front use)

Comment: I think better check on that with front-end, based on that it is possible to look for proper string to be sent in `text`